# How to create a JavaScript wrapper that can access a function and it's objects?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that must be intact and cannot be modified.

```
        function newUser(username, email, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var response;
            var success = (!!Math.round(Math.random()));

            if (!success){
                response = JSON.stringify({
                    success: success,
                    error: "Oups, something went wrong!"
                });
            } else {
                response = JSON.stringify({
                    success: success,
                    user: {
                        username: username,
                        email: email
                    }
                });   
            }

            xhr.open("POST", "/echo/json/");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                }
            }
            xhr.send("json=" + response);
        };
```

First I would like to call a function (newUser) on Click and then I would like to display and alert when the AJAX request within that function is successful. So far I have something similar to

```
            var el = document.getElementById("myButton");
            el.onclick = addUser;

               if (success){
                    alert (‘successful’);
                    }
```

Since I can't modify the addUser function I figured that I need to add some sort of JavaScript wrapper to access it. Maybe I'm overthinking it but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @James: Just edit the typo in the future. No need for extra comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand your question, but let me try to help.  Specify a handler function:

```
function onSuccess(result){
   alert (‘successful’)
}
```

Then call `newUser`:

```
el.onclick = addUser("userName", "userEmal", onSuccess);
```

`onSuccess` will be invoked in case of a `200` response, per the source code you provided.